# backbone.js models analogue in python

Tags: python, json, orm, model, backbone.js

Im working on project, which can be shipped as server version or stand-alone distributive. It is DB-agnostic by architecture, and all data records have KV form. Value is serialized json data with one of the existing structures.

And i need some solution, providing very basic ORM level to manage set of this records without database dependency, which can manage dict and lists, track changes, perform simple validation and provide some hooks for syncing set of records with global or local storage, even the file-based ones.

backbone.js models is very close to what i want, but i cant find analogue on python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if its exactly what you want, but I'm working on a project which implements a light-weight - ORM-like framework (designed to be similar to, but much lighter than, [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).  It's still very much beta, but it does work: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/norman/0.5.0

Otherwise I'd suggest you have a look at [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for a much more complex and structured ORM.

Comment: Norman is ok, thank you!

Alchemy is good project which i using in other projects, but it is strong tied with SQL relational databases and does not fit.

Comment: Btw, Norman is currently only Python3.  If there is any demand for it I'll backport to 2.7, so if this is a problem post an issue on the tracker and I'll look into backporting it.

Comment: Yeah, i've noticed.
I already tried to backport automatically with 3to2 tool, all tests is ok except database cause unhandled py3 metaclass in the test itself that 3to2 can't handle.
3to2 output is crispy, and i'm using it to locate hard places before manual clean.

Comment: I know what's causing the error you're talking about.  If you'd like to add a patch to the issue tracker I can sort out the hard places for you and add it to the code base.

Comment: I already made backport, only trouble was new style metaclesses with kwargs, just replaced database=db to __database__=db property in table class declaration and add some strings to TableMeta.__new__ to handle this property correct. Unvortuantly this solution requiring different tables declaration in code. Maybe something like small fabric wrap can help to solve it.

Comment: My idea was a class decorator, but I'll work on a formal backport for the next release.

Comment: I can pick up this work, anyway i already made package for 2.x with smooth tests. Maybe it makes sense to continue the direct interaction cause i'm including this ORM in project, that will require support and further development for some years and  interested not seeing 2.x branch in decline. My mail post.ilya@gmail.com, skype: blinkedeye